# Using a UIViewController.view as a tableHeaderView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having trouble getting the UI elements to appear in the tableHeaderView of a UITableView. I instantiated a property called headerView (UIView), and set it to the .view property of the viewController. I then set the heightForHeaderInSection method to be the headerView.frame.height. When the table is displayed, the height of the header is correct, however none of the embedded UI elements of the ViewController is visible in the headerView.

Is this a supported method to do this kind of thing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is not how UIViewControllers work.

You need to add the UITableView to the UIViewController by saying

```
self.view.addSubview(tableView)
```

Then you set the UITableView.headerView as the headerView you created by saying

```
tableView.headerView = headerView
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I might not have described what I did the best I could have. I essentially did that, and that is not working. I created the headerView property as anotherViewController.view, and tried to set this to be the headerview of the table. The header's size is correct, however the headerview is just a blank view.

Comment: Did you add any elements to the headerView?

Comment: let headerView = ViewController.view 
tableview.tableHeaderView = headerView

This is essentially what I'm trying to do.